# SE 2.0 Meta doesn't award rep, but it refers to "rep"

Tags: bug, status-completed, reputation, voting, per-site-meta

I [originally posted this on MSF](http://meta.serverfault.com/questions/472/se-2-0-meta-doesnt-award-rep-but-it-refers-to-rep), but it got no response, so at the suggestion made in a comment there, I'm reposting it here.

---

[image: Meta Rep]
<sub>(source: [netstrata.com](http://netstrata.com/images/metarep.png))</sub>

---

This should be called "up-votes", or something like that, showing a count ("1" in this case) instead of a value.

I'm not sure what should be done with down-votes. Perhaps the tab should say "votes" and show "+X -Y".

As it is it implies that reputation is awarded.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The reputation tab is no longer shown on child metas, so this should no longer be an issue.

Answer (score 5):

Reputation *is* awarded on metas, it's just not shown next to your name in the top bar (the rep from the parent site is shown instead) -- but that "reputation" is still a valid measure of your participation in that meta.

Comment: You can even earn [badges](http://meta.nothingtoinstall.com/badges/144/mortarboard) for stuff like hitting the reputation cap.

Comment: Yes, you can [@Grace](http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/badges/144/mortarboard)

Comment: @Juan: So where would I go to see this shadow reputation?

Comment: @Dennis You can see it in the envelope report you have now. The devs also have access to it.

Comment: @Dennis: you can go to [your user page](http://meta.serverfault.com/users/1293/dennis-williamson) and just add everything up. :-D

Comment: Weird! Even the meta.sitename.com/reputation report says `Reputation on this per-site meta is derived entirely from the parent site; nothing to show.`

Comment: Yes, but I can't see *yours* (and I'm too lazy to add them up, especially since I'd have to do extra clicking to go page to page). @Grace: I'm assuming you mean the envelope report I included a screen shot of in my question. I don't think some of you see the distinction I'm making between *votes* and *score*.

Comment: @Dennis The distinction is the fact you earn more than 1 reputation per vote, you can see the score if you look under the "Reputation" tab, which includes acceptance and downvotes. Because it doesn't provide any utility to the site functionality, it isn't important for people to see what others have for reputation. It's primarily useful for measure of participation by the Team. Who, as mentioned earlier, are the ones who have clear access to it.

Comment: @Grace: There's no Reputation tab on SE 2.0 Meta sites.

Comment: @Dennis You circled it on your own screenshot.

Comment: @Grace: I thought you meant on the `users/nnnnn` page not the Recent Activity page.

Comment: hey, so what is the verdict? For me there is no rep tab on meta.math, but I got NO rep when my _question_ was upvoted (a couple of times)

Answer (score 2):

I see what you are talking about, but I suspect most meta visitors will quickly understand what is going on and will not really worry about it.  I am sure there are many other more important things to fix before this gets to the top of the task list.