# Recent Activity (Rep) Showing on Per-Site Meta

Tags: bug, status-completed, per-site-meta

This question would appear to be [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed) now that the rep tab is gone from SE2.0 metas and the /reputation URL returns nothing of interest:

[SE 2.0 Meta doesn't award rep, but it refers to "rep"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66370/153001)

But I see rep changes in the user dropdown:

[image: OMG Rep!]

Like most neurotic posters on meta I can't deal with even *the thought* of losing 1 rep.  Please fix this before I'm forced to take up residence in an insane asylum.

Comment: *Gasp* 2 *real* reps lost already *head explodes*.

Comment: *Gasp* make that 2 *real* reps lost, then replaced, then lost again the following month.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was an oversight, it'll be corrected in the next build.