# Appearance of badges in Meta don't match Main

Tags: support, badges, per-site-meta

I have noticed that in Meta, for example Biology Meta, I have the same reputation as in Biology, but the badges are different. The badges, however, seem pretty random as I own more badges in Meta than I deserved there (as far as I can track anyway). How does the badging system work in meta sites?

Comment: Which one of your badges (on what meta) are "undeserved"? Doesn't seem that any on the Biology meta are.

Comment: Reputation is by-design, per site meta does not have its own reputation, but is rather synched with the parent site. Badges however are separate, so if you can point out which exactly you think "you don't deserve" please explain and you might found a bug. :)

Comment: Whoops - upon checking, you guys are right.... I did deserve them all I guess.... Sorry about that, but I was so convinced that they just appeared at random :/ Anyway thanks for pointing this out. If this question should be edited or deleted I'm happy to.

Answer (score 1):

I just [answered](https://lifehacks.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2372/59) a [similar question](https://lifehacks.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2371/59) last night :)

Like Shadow Wizard [pointed out](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/247249/appearance-of-badges-in-meta#comment810346_247249), even though reputation is carried over from the Main site to a per-site-Meta, badges are kept separate. (see [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/117523/266359) for more on why that is)