# How is Yearling badge awarded on metas?

Tags: support, badges, per-site-meta, yearling-badge

How is [yearling](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/help/badges/13/yearling) badge calculated on (per site) metas? In particular, what is used as reputation? I would expect that the upvotes from meta are used here, bud this does not seem to be the case. (The description of the badge is: *Active member for a year, earning at least 200 reputation. This badge can be awarded multiple times.*)

For example, I have noticed that many users have received this badge on (relatively new) [mathoverflow meta](https://meta.mathoverflow.net/help/badges/13/yearling). Some of the users having this badge don't have any post on meta for that site, so they cannot have any upvotes to their posts there. I have also noticed several users with no posts having this badge on [meta.math.SE](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/help/badges/13/yearling).

Based on this, I guess that rep from the main site is used. Is this the case? Does this mean that this badge will be awarded more-or-less at the same time on the main site and on meta?

Comment: Well, the reps for a site is the same as the meta. I got the badge for SU the same time I got it for SU meta

Comment: Well, the rep *shown* on meta is the same as on the main site. But still rep for meta is probably stored somewhere - I suppose tag badges or Mortarboard and similar badges are awarded based on "meta reputation".

Comment: See also: [SE 2.0 Meta doesn't award rep, but it refers to “rep”](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66370/se-2-0-meta-doesnt-award-rep-but-it-refers-to-rep)

Comment: It seems this is the case---you receive the yearling badges on a site and its meta at the same time. I received the yearling badge on meta.philosophy.SE without ever having asked or answered any questions there, and I'm pretty sure I didn't first log in to both the site and its meta at the same time.